# Using Multer Storage Object

Tags: node.js, npm, multer

I am using `multer` to upload files to the server.  Everything works fine except for one issue that is actually mentioned in the `multer` documentation. Here is an excerpt:

> "Note that `req.body` might not have been fully populated yet" (meaning when the storage object filename function is called I guess...). "It depends on the order that the client transmits fields and files to the server"

This is exactly where my problem is. I did verify that the `req.body.ID` makes it to the server, yet it is populated after `multer` defines the name of the file.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to deal with this problem?  Here are my code snippets (the file name ends up being "Undefined" with the correct jpg extension):

```
//Storage object
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './uploaded',
  filename: function(req, res, cb) {
    cb(null, req.body.ID + '.jpg')
  }
});

//File Upload Handle
router.post('/file-upload', upload.single('image'), function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("routes module-/file-upload " + req.body.ID); // The file ID gets transmitted
  res.sendStatus(201);
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="fileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

    <div class="form-group">
        <input id='name' name="name" placeholder="ID" class="form-control-label">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" align="center">
        <input type="file" id="file" name="image"> 
    </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"  value="Upload">Upload</button>

</form>
```

and front-end AJAX:

```
//Testing Files Uploads
$("#fileForm").on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  var fileID = $('#name').val();
  formData.append("ID", fileID);

  $.ajax('/file-upload', {
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
    })
    .done(function(item) {
      console.log('Uploaded!');
    })
    .error(function() {
      console.log('doesnt work!')
    });
});

//End of Files Uploads
```

Comment: You might add what your form submission looks like on the client side (especially the HTML form if you are using that).

Comment: Good suggestion, thank you, the HTML form is quite simple, adding it now

Comment: @pastrop: Could you also post how you are assigning the storage object above to multer? eg:

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post('/profile', upload.single('uploadedFile'), function (

Answer (score 0):

I believe `req.body.ID` is incorrect. It is quite possible you were trying to use `req.body.name`? 
When I used your example, I also got Undefined.jpg. But using the `.name`, i got the right filename

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late to the party, but I encountered the exact problem as you. I mitigated the problem by saving the file to a temporary location, and in the callback function, move (rename) the said function to the desired location.